# migrate hibernateTemplate to JPA 2 (executeWithNativeSession - doInHibernate)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-batch, persistence.xml

I am migrating my code from hibernate 3 (that is using hibernate template) to JPA 2. My project is using Spring as well.

Current project is using hibernatetempate as

```
hibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(new HibernateCallback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws SQLException {
                Query query = session.getNamedQuery("updateToProcessed");
                query.setParameter("Id", id);
                return query.executeUpdate();
            }
        });
```

updateToProcessed is a simple update hql query. Please help to let me know how to convert it to JPA (to use entityManager)

I tried using

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("updateToProcessed");
        query.setParameter("Id", id);
        query.executeUpdate();
```

Complete method is

```
@Override
    public void updateAllBatchDetails(final String id) {
            Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("updateToProcessed");
            query.setParameter("Id", id);
            query.executeUpdate();
    }
```

But I am getting error as:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:333)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
```

I have configured transactionManager in applicationContext.xml like

I was expecting this answer and I have already configured that in applicationContext.xml but still I am getting that error

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
```

But somehow @Transactional is working that I don't want to use.

This is the applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.batch"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:batch.properties"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <import resource="classpath:core/applicationContext.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext-resources.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext-batch.xml"/>


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:persistenceUnitName="default"
          p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

    <bean id="batchProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"
          p:location="classpath:batch.properties"/>


</beans>
```

Comment: The error indicates that you haven't setup transactions properly. Make sure that you have the `JpaTransactionManager` configured and that you have marked the methods you want transactional as transactional, either with `@Transactional` and `<tx:annotation-driven />` or using a `<tx:advice />` and `<aop:config />` element.

Comment: I was expecting this answer and I have already configured that in applicationContext.xml but still I am getting that error

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

But somehow @Transactional is working that I don't want to use

Comment: The fact that you configured it doesn't mean it is correct. Judging from the stacktrace it isn't. My guess you have a component-scan and scanning for the same beans twice, leading to a proxied and unproxied instance.

Comment: checked it again and confirming that component-scan is done once only.

Comment: make sure that you are scanning in the same context as the `<tx:annotation-driven />` is in, else transactions won't be applied. Also make sure that, although you might have a single component-scan, the configurationi s only loaded once and not twice.

Comment: You are only posting snippets please post some full configuration, stacktraces including the web.xml and which files are loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` and which are loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`. Trust me you are scanning or constructing objects twice somewhere else transactions would have been applied.  I also assume you use hibernate you aren't messing around with the `hibernate.current_session_context` property are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute a bulk update you should do like below:

```
final String updateQuery = "update Person p SET p.name = 'Other Name'";
final int update = entityManager.createQuery(updateQuery).executeUpdate();
System.out.println("updated rows " + update);
```

Spring will handle the commit for you. [=

---

Edit: Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException

Have you configured the Transaction? To execute a update you must open a transaction.

With Spring you could use the annotation @Transactional in the method.

Comment: Thanks for that. I already tried that in this way:

Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("updateToProcessed");
        query.setParameter("id", Id);
        query.executeUpdate();

But it is giving me the error:

Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:71)

Comment: Edited the question again. Added the transactionManager configuration but not working with configuration.

Comment: Could you post the method that is using the EntityManager?

Comment: edited the question. Method was already posted without signature but now the complete method is posted.

Comment: Take a look at the edit in my comment, you need to annotate it with @Transactional

Comment: but if transaction config is there, it should work. I posted the config. Just want to know why that is not working?

Comment: Where did you see that it should work only with the transaction config? I believe that this would be a wrong behavior, imagine that for every incoming request a new transaction would be opened in the controller. You need to tell the Spring where you want an active transaction.

Comment: I am doing that with all jpa using transactional anootation with read only false and then update with readonly true. thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem use a [Tasklet](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/Tasklet.html) where you execute your query.
Configure a step using a [TaskletStep](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/TaskletStep.html) and you can set 'transaction manager' as well as 'transaction attributes' and errors should go away.

Comment: Thanks for that. But finding it too much complex to do that. I am using it as a decider in decision with some if else condition.